# How can I call the style of a new Library as parent in style.xml?

Tags: android, themes, android-theme, android-library, android-styles

I am building a new library for Android and a demo project that I am using to test the library.
The library that I made has a style called **Light** and in the demo I am applying this style in Java using `setTheme(R.style.Light)` but I would like to replace it calling the theme directly in style.xml. What I have right now in the demo/res/values/style.xml is

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

and I would like to replace it with something similar to:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="myLibrary.Light">
```

I have tried with `parent="@style/Light"` but it's not working.
Does anyone know how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

To inherit styles from a library or your own project, declare the parent style name without the @android:style/ part. For example, the following example inherits text appearance styles from the support library:

`<style name="GreenText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
</style>`
[For more details](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes)

Comment: That's to customise a default theme which I am already doing in my library. I am asking if it's possible to replace "parent" in style with a theme from my library then using a default theme from Android.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,
My problem was that in my library I had different styles depending on the version of Android. For each version of Android my main theme was referred to different parents by mistake. I just changed the parents in my library making sure that they are referring to the same one and it fixed my problem. Now in my app I can refer to the theme created in my library without crashing the application.